# Invalidate NSTimer after VC is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am having a `NSTimer` in my VC and its working fine its sending location of user and i cant invalidate it on `viewDidDisappear` as i need to send in background also.

```
myTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target: self
                                                 selector: @selector(sendDataToSocket) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
```

But the issue is when i instantiate same VC again it start the `NSTimer` again and 2 timers are working. so how can i stop the previous one or any other solution

Any help will be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: why can't you invalidate it at viewDidDisappear? if your timer is still active but your VC gets deallocated, I think it will crash as timer's delegate has been deallocated...

Comment: Because i need to send he location when its in background or any other screen.. And there is no such crashing issue

Answer (score 0):

you should handle the timer instantiation mechanism in your `AppDelegate`

so, in your `ViewController`, every time you instantiate it, you can call

```
[((YourAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate) startMyTimer:self];
```

where `startMyTimer` could be defined like this

```
-(void)startMyTimer:(id)aTarget
{
    if(myTimer)
    {
         [myTimer invalidate];
         myTimer = nil;
    }
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 2.0
                                               target: aTarget
                                             selector: @selector(sendDataToSocket)
                                             userInfo: nil 
                                              repeats: YES];
}
```

so you are sure that only one `myTimer` is always active in your app and you can call your ViewController's `sendDataToSocket`

Comment: A question in my mind is i take mytimer as @property and when ever i instantiate this vc at that time if i invalidate first and then in again didload it will start

Comment: You have two choices: (1) the first is to invalidate the first myTimer you start when the VC it belongs to *dies* or (2) to move it somewhere else where it can live forever because the handler *never dies*. In fact, if you instantiate again your VC, then you do not have anymore any reference to the first myTimer, so you have two working myTimers, as you already said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the singleton class or simple use the appDelegate class to just declare the `myTimer` object in appDelegate and use it in your viewController.

This will have a single object of timer and you dont need to create multiple objects and your ultimate objective will be resolved. Hope this Helps!

Comment: should i take only mytimer as property in AppDelegate

Comment: Yes you need to add in AppDelegate